# passing variables from Html StageWebview to actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

How can I get the username field data and pass it to Actionscript?
Please help I wrote this code as an example of what I'm trying to do...

Get the data from the username and pass it to `txtc.text` in Flash:

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 200, 200, this.stage.stageWidth, 
this.stage.stageHeight); 
webView.stage = this.stage; 
var htmlString:String = "<form action='/action_page.php'>" +
"First name:<br>" +
"<input type='text' name='firstname' value='Mickey'><br>" +
"Last name:<br>" +
"<input type='text' name='lastname' value='Mouse'><br><br>" +
"<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
"</form>";
webView.loadString(htmlString);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn21e);
function btn21e(event:MouseEvent):void
{
txtc.text = String(htmlString); 
}
```

Comment: Is this solved? If not, try adding some Javascript function to copy text entries when "submit" button is pressed, then use `External Interface` in AS3 to receive back the text from the running Javascript function...

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, StageWebView is isolated for security reasons, so you won't get your result. However, there is a StageWebView ANE from MyFlashLabs, that should be able to get/pass results from/into the StageWebView.